# tableview load image async but sometimes some cell will never load successfully?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview

I want tableview to load images async,

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
  StickerListItemView *rowView = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:StickerTableViewIdentifier
                                                         owner:self];
  if (!rowView) {
    rowView = [[StickerListItemView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 460, 300)];
    rowView.identifier = StickerTableViewIdentifier;
    id obj = [self.stickerListArray objectAtIndex:row];
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[StickerListModel class]]) {
    StickerListModel *listModel = (StickerListModel *)obj;
    rowView.productId = listModel.productId;
    rowView.title = listModel.name;
    rowView.intro = listModel.intro;
    rowView.status = [self hasStickersDownloaded:listModel.productId];
    [rowView setDelegate:self];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^(void) {
      NSImage *image = [self getPreviewImageWithMd5:listModel.md5OfPrieviewImage];
      //****************************************
      NSLog(@"get image at index %ld",(long)row);
       if (image) {
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         rowView.image = image;
         [rowView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
         //**************************************
         NSLog(@"set image at row %ld",(long)row);
         });
       }
    });
  }
}
return rowView;
```

}

Sometimes, it will load successfully, but sometimes one cell will never load the image, just like the picture below: the 
[image]

I wait for long time, but the third image never loaded.

Comment: depends what you want to fix!  If it's going to take some time to load the data, I would normally initialise the tableView with 'loading...' or similar, and then in the completion closure, if the load fails, you can either update the display to 'unavailable', or retry - but you need to limit how often you do that , or you could get stuck in a loop forever.  The important thing is to make sure that you can handle success and failure, and update the display accordingly

Comment: @Russell Really thank for the help, I know your meaning, and I have complemented my question, I have tested for several times. And turns out the first cell to load is always can't load successfully, I really don't know why the first one is always fail. Maybe there is limit of the count of urlconnection?

Comment: It looks like your `image` object created with `getPreviewImageWithMd5` is NULL. You should check in this method.

Comment: silly question - but is it always the same image (index 3), or is it always the first one that it tries?

Comment: @Russell sorry for my poor english, the latter one, it is always the first one that it tries.

Comment: @Russell  in getPreviewImageWithMd5: I get the image with   [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]] , but when I changed it to [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest...] it all worked. But I know little about the async and sync, so I still don't know the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this line is returning nil.

```
NSImage *image = [self getPreviewImageWithMd5:listModel.md5OfPrieviewImage];
```

You should check the value of image to make sure it's not nil and possibly add some error handling. Maybe something like this.

```
if (image) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        rowView.image = image;
        [rowView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
        NSLog(@"set image at row %ld",(long)row);
     });
} else {
    NSLog(@"Received nil image for row %ld", (long)row);
    //possibly set a placeholder image for this row instead
}
```

Comment: thanks for the advice, I will handle like this. And in  getPreviewImageWithMd5: I create the image with [nsimage imageWithData:[NSData dateWithContentsOfURl:]] ,I googled this one is operated in main queue, maybe it is the reason of this problem I guess, because I changed it to [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest......] and it all worked, well, I guess, do you know the reason, really thanks for the help~

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just know that I should click the check to mark the accepted answer.